# Estimate involving gradient and Laplacian

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $U$ be a bounded region in n-dimensional space. Let $u(x,t)$, with $x\in U$ and $t>0$ be smooth and zero on $\partial U$. I have to prove the estimate
$$
\int_U |\nabla u|^2 \leq C \int_U |\Delta u|^2,
$$
where $C$ is some constant and must be related to the first eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ of the Laplacian.

According to Evans PDE $\lambda_1=\min_{u \in H_0^1(U),u\neq 0} \frac{\int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^2 \;dx}{\int_{\Omega} |u|^2 \; dx}$.
I thought about using integration by parts to get
$$
\int_U u_{x_i}u_{x_i} \; dx = -\int_U u u_{x_i x_i} \; dx,
$$
summing over $i$ to get
$$
\int_U |\nabla u|^2 =  -\int_U u \Delta u,
$$
then using Holder's inequality
$$
-\int_U u \Delta u \leq \left( \int_U |u|^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \left( \int_U |\Delta u|^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.
$$
I don't see how to go on from here (if I'm in the right direction).

Comment: I'm not able to work this all out atm but I feel like the [Poincarè inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincaré_inequality) could help out here.

Comment: Also you didn't specify what space $u$ lies in, but I'm guessing $H^2(U \times (0,\infty))$?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the exercise $u$ is smooth. I thought this means that $u \in C^{\infty}$.

Comment: Could I just substitute $\int_U |u|^2$ with $\frac{\int_U |\nabla u|^2}{\lambda_1}$?

Comment: yes, exactly, this is what mkl314's answer says to do so I would accept his answer. Note that once you have this you can consider $|\nabla u|$ a function in itself and apply the inequality again.

Comment: I would like to accept his answer, but his constant is not related to the first eigenvalue of the Laplacian. Should I still mark this as accepted then?

Answer (score 2):

The rest is easy. You just need to apply the Friedrichs inequality 
$$
\int_U |u|^2 dx \leq C_h \int_U |\nabla u|^2 dx \quad\forall\, u\in H^1(U)\colon\;
u|_{\partial U}=0,
$$
valid for any Lipschitz  domain $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ bounded in at least one direction, *i.e.*, condained in some
layer of width $h>0$ (see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrichs%27_inequality).

Comment: Eh I always confuse this one with *Poincarès Inequality*, I think my PDE book even calls this "Poincarès Inequality" xD